# Python best way to return multiple values or error from method

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a method/function that queries a database and return 3 values if the searched value exists in the database table.
If there are no results or an error ocurrs, I need to identify that so I can use it in a conditional statement.

So far I have this:

```
def read_log(self,ftpsource):
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect(...)
        sql_query=f"""Select ID,file_modif_date,size FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE Source='{ftpsource}'"""
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_query)
        for row in cursor:
            id=row[0]
            file_mtime=row[1]
            file_size=row[2]
        return('1',id,file_mtime,file_size)
    except Exception as e:
        return('0','0','0','0')

#Call the function
   sql_status,id,time,size = log.read_log('hol1a')
   if sql_status!=0:
       print(id,time,size)
   elif sql_status==0:
       print("Error")
```

But doesn't looks good to me.. So I wonder, what is the best practice to return multiple values and identify if there are no values or an error ocurrs, with a function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no *one best way* to return values.

Do you return coordinates, vectors? It is obvious that it will return more than one value and what values to expect?

```
def get_position2d():
    return x, y
```

If the returned values are not obvious/ordered you may need names, using a dictionary!

```
def get_ingredients():
    return {'sugar': 10, 'salt': 30, 'flour': 150, 'turobo_reactor': 1}
```

Do you return big datasets for machine learning? Use Pandas or numpy arrays!

```
import pandas as pd
def get_input_data():
    # Imagine this is a 5k+ entries dataset...
    return pd.DataFrame(dict(
        speed=[1,2,3,4,5], heat=[50,50,35,24,10], tire_type=[1,1,1,1,2]))
```

The one rule is that it should make sense and should be considered as "one element". For a position, x and y are one element in the sense that they are "the position". Same for ingredients, they are the "ingredients for one specific recipe".

So avoid mixing nonsensical return values. One function, one job, one output (within the current context).

Finally, you may want to consider if the data you return should be [mutable or immutable](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-towardsdatascience-com-python-basics-mutable-vs-immutable-objects-829a0cb1530a). If you are going to modify the data afterwards you may need to use lists instead of sets.

Now, about errors!

If you are talking about Python errors, you can only have one error at a time. So the following code should allow you to catch errors and play with them.

```
def i_will_throw_an_error():
    try:
        do_something_bad()
    except:
        do_something_if_a_bad_thing_happens()
```

Now if you talk about error messages and values, you may (or may not) want to trigger a Python error if the data given to you was wrong!

```
def i_get_bad_data_and_i_raise_it():
    bad_data = get_bad_data()
    if(bad_data['is_really_bad'] is True):
        raise ValueError('Oh no, the data we got is really bad!')
```